# Netgear WNDR4700 weird connection issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a WNDR4700 I just got back from a long weekend and the router is acting strange. I have several devices connected to it with different out comes.

- Windows 10 HTPC - no connection issues
- Xbox 360 ethernet - no issues
- Xbox 360 over Wifi - will connect but not reach the internet
- Wink Hub (WiFi) - no issues
- GS3 - will connect but no Internet
- Droid Turbo - will connect but no Internet
- Windows 10 laptop. - will connect but "limited". network center say unidentified network. When I connect it via Ethernet it will fully connect but after a while it dropped to a unidentified network.

I have done multiple restarts on both the router and devices. I also did a factory reset on the router but no luck.

Comment: It sounds like it could be a few things, I wish I could comment to ask these questions. Can you a screen shot or a print of your ipconfig -all (cmd) when connected via Wifi Have you updated the firmware on the device to the latest as well. http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23728 Lastly, are you using IPv4, IPv6, or Both? I've also done a few searches and see that this happens often sometimes resulting in an RMA request -many years in the IT field.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I am on the latest firmware.
I will grab you a screen shot when I get home as I cant remote into the computer due to lack of connection.
IPv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The wink home automation hub was somehow acting as a DHCP server.  The Hub does have the ability to do so in order to perform its initial set up and connect to your home network but mine was already connected.  So something went wrong with it but after unplugging it everything was fine.  I plugged it back in and it appears power cycling it resolved the issue.